# which one is a faster/better sql practice?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Suppose I have a 2 column table (id, flag) and id is sequential. 
I expect this table to contain a lot of records. 
I want to periodically select the first row not flagged and update it. Some of the records on the way may have already been flagged, so I want to skip them.

Does it make more sense if I store the last id I flagged and use it in my select statement, like

```
select * from mytable where id > my_last_id order by id asc limit 1
```

or simply get the first unflagged row, like:

```
select * from mytable where flagged = 'F' order by id asc limit 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: (possibly a typo) Does " flagged='F' " mean that your record is UNflagged?

Comment: good point.. F stands for false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `MySQL`, this one:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   flagged = 'F'
ORDER BY
        flagged ASC, id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

will be slightly less efficient in `InnoDB` and of same efficiency in `MyISAM`, if you have an index on `(flagged, id)`.

`InnoDB` tables are clustered on the `PRIMARY KEY`, so fetching the first record in `id` does not require looking up the table.

In `MyISAM`, tables are heap-organized, so the index used to police the `PRIMARY KEY` is stored separately from the table.

Note the `flagged` in the `ORDER BY` clause may seem to be redundant, but it is required for `MySQL` to pick the correct index.

Also, the composite index should be on `(flagged, id)` even in `InnoDB` (which implicitly includes the `PRIMARY KEY` into each index).

Comment: what is the point of ordering by `flagged` since it is the filter ( *with one allowed value in the resultset* )... it is useless...

Comment: @Quassnoi, if it is an intrinsic issue with the implementation then i declare my ignorance on it :) it just seems pretty un-intuitive.. (edit: thanks for the additional info, makes more sense now :) )

Comment: @artsince: in absolute terms, both queries will be instant (order of magnitude of milliseconds) and the difference will be imperceptible, as long as you create the indexes. However, the first query (with only `id`) will be one page lookup faster in `InnoDB`, FWIW.

Comment: I suppose that depending on what values are possible for "flag" you'd need to change whether the index is ascending or descending on that column?

Comment: @ninesided: `MySQL` does not support descending indexes. You should change direction in `ORDER BY` and directions of all columns should match for the index to be usable.

Answer (score 3):

If you create an index on flagged, retrieving an unflagged row should be pretty much an instant operation. If you always update them sequentially, then the first method is fine though.

Answer (score 2):

Option two is the only one that makes sense unless you know that you're always going to process records in sequence!

Comment: I know that I will always process them in order.

Comment: @Gaby, I realise this, but there's nothing saying that there couldn't be unprocessed records with an id below that of the "latest processed id". This would leave you with holes in your data that could never be filled based on the logic of the first query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Select Min(Id) as 'Id'
From dbo.myTable
Where Flagged='F'
```

Assuming the Flagged = 'F' means that it is not flagged.

Comment: Ah yes of course.  Although I am not sure why you would <code>*</code> in this scenario.